# Ordering django model queryset based on child model which has OneToOne Relation with parent

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Here are my Django Models

##### Product Model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='productCategory')
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='productBrand')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    hsnCode = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
   .
   .
   .
```

##### Product Inventory Model

```
class ProductInventory(models.Model):
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="productInventory")
    inventoryInWarehouse = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    .
    .
    .
```

I want to order the query set based on high to low inventory what will be the queryset for this

I want to Product order like this

```
| product | price | ..... | inventory |
| ------  | ----- | ----- | --------- |
| T-shirt | 647   | ...   | 100       |
| xxxxxxx | 876   | ...   | 78        |
| xxxxxxx | 356   | ...   | 64        |
| xxxxxxx | 878   | ...   | 43        |
| xxxxxxx | 999   | ...   | 23        |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
queryset = Product.objects.all().order_by('-vendorProduct__inventoryInWarehouse')
```

Here vendorProduct is a related name